# save TextField content in an custom dynamic tableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, xcode4.3, ios5.1

I've got a custom TableViewCell with a dynamic tableviewcontroller
[screenshot of my app](http://i44.tinypic.com/6dtr3l.jpg)

the products are saved in CoreData and i can fetch them (Name,price etc.) but i don't know how to implement the amount of the products. its a textfield and i want to save the textfield when  i click on the basket button.

here is my TableViewCell.h:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface ProduktTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>

 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *produktnameLabel;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *preisLabel;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *vonDatumLabel;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *menge;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *bisDatumLabel;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *datumButton;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *warenkorbButton;
 @end
```

TableViewCell.m:

```
 #import "ProduktTableViewCell.h"

 @implementation ProduktTableViewCell
 @synthesize produktnameLabel;
 @synthesize preisLabel;
 @synthesize vonDatumLabel;
 @synthesize bisDatumLabel;
 @synthesize datumButton;
 @synthesize menge;
 @synthesize warenkorbButton;


 @end
```

my ProductViewController.m:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ProduktTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"produktCell"];

    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.produktnameLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"produktname"]; 
    cell.vonDatumLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"vondatum"];
    cell.bisDatumLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"bisdatum"]; 
    cell.datumButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.warenkorbButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.menge.tag = indexPath.row;


    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *german = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"];
    [formatter setLocale:german];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];


    NSNumber *firstNumber = [managedObject valueForKey:@"preis"];

    cell.preisLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:firstNumber];



    return cell;
}
```

my basket button:

```
- (IBAction)warenkorbButton:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext]; 
    UIButton *button = sender;
    NSInteger rowInIndexPath =button.tag;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowInIndexPath inSection:0];
    Warenkorb *warenkorb = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Warenkorb" inManagedObjectContext:context];

   Produkt *produkt = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    warenkorb.produktname  =produkt.produktname ;
    warenkorb.vondatum = produkt.vondatum;
    warenkorb.bisdatum = produkt.bisdatum;
    warenkorb.preis =produkt.preis;

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Fehler beim hinzufügen : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I understood. You want to get the value entered on the text field. (Right?) In ProduktTableViewCell.h, create an outlet for your UITableView element in the xib file--So, something like:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

Please take care of the property attributes. The code above is just an example. Then, on ProduktTableViewCell.m synthesize `myTableView` and declare a global variable:

```
static NSIndexPath *myIndexPath;
```

Next, on `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` save the indexPath:

```
myIndexPath = indexPath;
```

Also, assign a unique value to `cell.menge.tag`:

```
cell.menge.tag = indexPath.row + 437812;
```

Now, in `- (IBAction)warenkorbButton:(id)sender` extract the cell containing the text field and eventually getting the text field:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIndexPath];
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row + 437812];
```

Finally, the text is in `textField.text`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes thats right but i can't access to self.menge.text, because its in the tableviewcell not in tableviewcontroller. i don't know how to access the textfield from the tableviewcontroller

Comment: @ErayGeveci, I have updated my answer. Please notify me about the result. :)

Comment: By the way, I am assuming that the cell in ProduktTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"produktCell"]; is not nil.

Comment: thank you very much. it works. Xcode shows me a warning at : static NSIndexPath *myIndexPath;    is this normal?

Comment: which is the unused variable? anyway, if it says so, i mean if the warning says unused variable, you can remove that.